# проблема синхронизации времени на нескольких смартфонах

Tags: android, время, synchronized

Стоит задача синхронизировать время на смартфонах через wifi, мобильную сеть или общий сервер. Есть приложение на Android с доступом к системному времени, но на разных смартфонах время идет по-разному. Необходимо, чтобы в приложение на разных смартфонах поступало одно и то же время (для одновременности включения записи звука). Я пробовал добавить в мой проект (DataRecorderApp) такой проект - (SyncAdapter) https://github.com/Cheticamp/SyncTrouble, есть интересный проект https://github.com/niliqiang/PTPdemo но они оба не работают, в первом проекте создается аккаунт, но синхронизация аккаунта не происходит

[image: Screenshot_20210422-025130].

Во втором случае Хронометраж времени стоит на месте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как запустить синхронизацию времени с помощью SyncAdapter , или есть ли другие способы это сделать через wifi, мобильную сеть или общий сервер?

Comment: Синхронизация акка, вроде бы, тут не причём. Второй пример, возможно, не работает из-за неработающего сервера. Попробуйте поменять сервер на рабочий, если дело в этом.

Comment: во втором примере стоит ip: 10.112.35.226, тогда как же найти действующий сервер?

Comment: Если по указанному IP не было что-то типа клона чего-то типа этого https://www.ntp-servers.net/servers.html, то надо у автора примера узнавать. Больше ничего добавить не могу(

Comment: А все-таки как мне использовать SyncAdapter? Как достать полезную информацию (точное время)? Я запустил отдельно программу на телефоне, не стал его добавлять в свой основной проект, и в настройках телефона в созданном аккаунте появился флажок синхронизации.

Comment: SyncAdapter не смотрел. Мне кажется, что это не про время, а про данные пользователя.